# How can you force a memory limit in Django WSGI apps?

Tags: django, apache, memory, memory-management, mod-wsgi

I want my app to throw an `MemoryError` when its usage goes over 1GB. I'm running in WSGI daemon mode.

I see 3 places the memory limit could be:

- apache.conf
- wsgi somewhere
- django configuration

but I can't find the right config options. In PHP you can do this with :

`php_value memory_limit 1GB`

in your `apache.conf`

Answer (score 3):

Resource memory limits aren't implemented on most platforms even though C API definitions exist. As such, mod_wsgi doesn't try to implement such restrictions. If PHP is doing it, is is able to do so by virtue that that it is a more constrained and controlled environment than Python.

The only portable way is to have a separate daemon process running which runs 'ps' or uses '/proc' to monitor memory usage of processes and then send a SIGINT signal to those which go over some predefined value.

---

UPDATE

Version 3.4 of mod_wsgi supports options for daemon mode that may be able to restrict memory usage. See:

- http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ChangesInVersion0304

Whether they work depends on the operating system you are using.

Comment: yikes, that sounds rough. Other people must solve this problem too right? Is there a standard daemon to do this job?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`resource.setrlimit()`](http://docs.python.org/library/resource.html#resource.setrlimit) with [`resource.RLIMIT_VMEM`](http://docs.python.org/library/resource.html#resource.RLIMIT_VMEM).

Comment: for some reason, resource doesn't have that on my debian system (python 2.5) `>>> dir(resource)
['RLIMIT_AS', 'RLIMIT_CORE', 'RLIMIT_CPU', 'RLIMIT_DATA', 'RLIMIT_FSIZE', 'RLIMIT_MEMLOCK', 'RLIMIT_NOFILE', 'RLIMIT_NPROC', 'RLIMIT_OFILE', 'RLIMIT_RSS', 'RLIMIT_STACK', 'RLIM_INFINITY', 'RUSAGE_CHILDREN', 'RUSAGE_SELF', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', 'error', 'getpagesize', 'getrlimit', 'getrusage', 'setrlimit', 'struct_rusage']` Which of those constants means the same thing?

Comment: You could probably get away with `resource.RLIMIT_RSS`.